# Meteor: Download a webpage from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, meteor

I want to get the json response from graph.facebook.com on the server. I thought it would be a good idea to use the $.get method providing by jQuery, but it seems that Meteor do not use jQuery on the server.

```
$.ajax
    url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + id
    success: (data, status) ->
        console.log data
```

This triggers the following error:

```
$ is not defined
```

I have run "meteor add jQuery", but same result. So first, is there a better way to get the json response from graph.facebook.com than using $.get? If not, how can I enable jQuery on the server?

Comment: jQuery is a client-side only library, you cannot use it on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to do it in Meteor would be to add a standard `http` package:

```
meteor add http
```

and now you can use `HTTP.get`, `HTTP.post` and others with the same API on the client and server:

```
HTTP.post("someurl", { data: myData }, function callback (err, response) {
  // do something
});
```

Notice that on the server side it can also be written in a "blocking style":

```
var response = HTTP.post("someurl", { data: myData });
```

See [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http);

Comment: By the way, you can use the retry package to make the http call even more reliable. http://meteorhacks.com/how-to-use-the-new-meteor-retry-package.html